# How to enable autocomplete for my rails functions?

Tags: autocompletion, filetype-ruby

How can I add auto-complete for my Rails project? I want autocomplete for existing rails functions, including gems, and for functions I created.

I hope there is some plugin for smart auto-complete, to recognize which object method will be called, and to offer relevant methods.

I have `vim-rails` plugin, but can not get working auto-complete. I am using Ubuntu 12, and regular vim.

I have successfully set up auto-complete for my `c++` files, it recognizes which libraries I have included and offers relevant functions for object on which the method will be called.

Comment: Fully autocompleting Ruby is much harder than C++ due to the dynamic nature of Ruby. Rails uses quite a bit of the "meta-programming" features of Ruby. For example, [completing something like this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1344) will be very hard unless you're running a full Rails application.